# Why does DataFrame.map throw Nothing match exception?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

- spark-core:2.2.0
- spark-sql: 2.2.0
- scala: 2.11.8

I have two piece of code which are similar but one works and the other does not.

The one that works:

```
private def loadValidStations() = {
  dfReader.csv(filePath + "stations.csv")
  .withColumn("lat", 'lat.cast(DoubleType))
  .withColumn("lon", 'lon.cast(DoubleType))
  .filter('lat.isNotNull && 'lon.isNotNull && !('stn.isNull && 'wban.isNull))
  .map(row => {
    val stn = row.getAs[String]("stn")
    val modifiedStn = if (stn == null) "_" else stn
    val wban = row.getAs[String]("wban")
    val modifiedWban = if (wban == null) "_" else wban

    (modifiedStn + "_" + modifiedWban, Location(row.getAs[Double]("lat"), row.getAs[Double]("lon")))
  })
}
```

The one that does not work:

```
private def getValidLocTemp(year: Int) = {
 dfReader.csv(filePath + year + ".csv")
  .withColumn("temp", 'temp.cast(DoubleType))
  .filter(!('stn.isNull && 'wban.isNull))
  .map(row => {             // exception of this line
    val stn = row.getAs[String]("stn")
    val modifiedStn = if (stn == null) "_" else stn
    val wban = row.getAs[String]("wban")
    val modifiedWban = if (wban == null) "_" else wban

    (modifiedStn + "_" + modifiedWban, row.getAs("month"), row.getAs("day"), row.getAs[Double]("temp"))
  })
}
```

For the one which does not work, I can print `count()` and `show(10)` and it contains 2190974 rows, but when I tried to `map`, it throws exception of this:

```
17/08/07 11:41:13 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on 192.168.56.1:58389 (size: 20.6 KB, free: 1987.5 MB)
17/08/07 11:41:13 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from csv at Extraction_SparkSQL.scala:74
17/08/07 11:41:13 INFO FileSourceScanExec: Planning scan with bin packing, max size: 5876545 bytes, open cost is considered as scanning 4194304 bytes.

Nothing (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassNoArgsTypeRef)
scala.MatchError: Nothing (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassNoArgsTypeRef)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:706)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$9.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:385)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$9.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:384)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$deserializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:384)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.deserializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:275)
at org.apache.spark.sql.LowPrioritySQLImplicits$class.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:233)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:33)
at observatory.Extraction_SparkSQL$.getValidLocTemp(Extraction_SparkSQL.scala:77)
at observatory.Extraction_SparkSQL$.extraction(Extraction_SparkSQL.scala:90)
at observatory.ExtractionTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ExtractionTest.scala:13)
at observatory.ExtractionTest$$anonfun$1.apply(ExtractionTest.scala:11)
at observatory.ExtractionTest$$anonfun$1.apply(ExtractionTest.scala:11)
at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
```

Comment: did you check after `.filter(!('stn.isNull && 'wban.isNull))` code if the dataframe contains any rows or not?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan hi, I could print the content and the size after filter, so it is not empty

Comment: you've already got the correct answer isn't it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you didn't provide type annotation for:

```
row.getAs("month")
```

and

```
row.getAs("day")
```

so Scala compiler types result to `Nothing`. Assuming it is `String`, this should resolve the problem:

```
(modifiedStn + "_" + modifiedWban, row.getAs[String]("month"), row.getAs[String]("day"), row.getAs[Double]("temp"))
```